# Hardcoded variables from database

Tags: python, django

What are the design patterns for variables which are stable for a long period, but can change in time? Let's assume income tax was 18% for 2015 and 2016, and from 1st January 2017 there would be 20%.

```
INCOME_TAX = 0.18

def _calculate_tax(self, income, tax=INCOME_TAX):
    return income*tax
```

When INCOME_TAX would be changed to 0.2 in 2017, the backward compatibility would be broken for previous years. I think there might be a  good idea to put this variables into database allowing to modify them somehow in admin panel, but there must be some industry standard or a good practice to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rate changes over time, it must be modeled by a time-dependent function.

How this function determines the right value for a given time point or time range is the next step:

1. If you hardcode the value into the program, you'll have to change the program after every change.
2. If you put it into the database, you have an additional DB query, but you can change it "in the implementation".
3. You an also - in the case of a widespread program - have the program load the right values from a central server and store it somewhere.

Depending on which solution you use, you can do

```
def calculate_tax_for_year(self, income, year):
    return _calculate_tax_for_year(self, income, tax_for_year(year)):

def tax_for_year(year): # solution 1
    if year < 2010: return .2
    if year < 2013: return .18
    # etc.

def tax_for_year(year): # solution 2
    with dbconn as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT rate FROM taxrate WHERE year == %s", year)
        return cursor.fetch_one_row() # don't remember the syntax; something like this...

# solution 3:
def tax_for_year(year):
    # just describing the steps:
    with open("path/to/taxfile", "r") as f:
        taxdata = f.read()
    # parse table file, e. g. CSV
    # find the right entry
    return entry_matching_for_given_year

def update_tax_file():
    import urllib
    conn = urllib.urlopen("http://my.taxfile/url.csv")
    # check if the file has changed since last check
    # if so:
    data = conn.read()
    with open("path/to/taxfile", "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little with code examples (2, 3)?

Answer (score 1):

If the rate changes, I'd add it to an intermediate step or in the database. It's not a true constant so you shouldn't treat it as one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want all previous rows to be recalculated after you change the `INCOME_TAX` variable then I'd suggest you adding an additional column to your table with `tax` value, so you know what was the tax for each entry.